# Choosing the right statistical analysis for my data

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-variable, continuous-data, qualitative

I have 20 field plots. In each plot, I have taken between 1000–1500 measurements (continuous values) of a given variable using an instrumental device and recorded information qualitatively through three variables that can take up to, respectively, two, three and four categories (observed categories).

I am interested in finding first which of these three qualitative variables have the most impact in the continuous response variable and, second, which categories from the qualitative variables influence the most the response variable. Any ideas on what statistical analysis to undertake?

Comment: $2*3*4=24$ combinations of the three exogenous variables. If you create a new variable which has 24 levels you can do a one-way ANOVA followed by a Tukey test for each combination, however you then lose information of between/within the variables, if this is of interest. Otherwise a three-way ANOVA is a possibility.

Comment: There is a random effect (field plot ID), so I thought it would not be possible to use ANOVA in this situation.

Comment: I see, you can use random effects with ANOVA, although it's not quite the same. If between/within variance is not of interest then the best option is a linear mixed model.

Comment: I have questions: 1) How many measurements did you take in each plot? 2) Was this an experiment or an observational study (that is, did you manipulate the variables?

Comment: Ansers to the questions: 1) Mininum number of measurements in each plot is 1000, but some plots have 1500. 2) The response variable was measured with a device, but the three explanatory variables (two, three and four categories, respectively) were observed.

Comment: @Darius: Please add this new information as an edit to the post. We want posts to be self-contained, and few people read comments ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you have random effects through the field plots and multiple covariates you want effect measures for, the most straightforward approach would be to use a linear mixed effects model (packages lme4 and lmertest if using R).

You would include a random intercept term for field ID (1|ID) as well as dummy variables for each covariate.